# Is it good approach to interact with smart contract using c# library instead of Web3-js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, c#

I'm learning Ethereum, and having web application development experience mostly with Microsoft Technologies such as ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI.

I've learned Solidity recently!. After reading about deployment of smart contract, what I found is *we need to deal with other js, framework(s) and many other tools*. One essential thing is Web3-js. To interact with smart contact, you need to learn Web3-js too!

But does it really required to learn Web3-js?(bit hard for newbie)

As I've knowledge of .NET, is it good approach to interact with smart contract using C# library(i.e Nethereum) and what are the disadvantages to use that library?

Answer (score 1):

** **BEWARE OPINION AHEAD** **

I don't know netEthereum that much but as far as i've seen, the most actively maintained and popular library for web3 is web3js (pyEthereum is somewhat popular also) due to the asynchronous nature of javascript as well as the number of js developers. So the likelihood of bugs is far less in web3js that's why it's far more recommended.

If you learned C# javascript will be so easy for you cause the c# syntax englobes the javascript one (ES6 exactly).

Hope it helps :)